# Remove the minimum number of vertices to find the chain in the graph

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, graph

I have a graph (not directed and not weighted) and its adjacency matrix (matrix type - boolean). I need to remove the minimum number of vertices to find the chain in this graph.
For the last two days I’ve been thinking about how to do this and haven’t come to any decision, so I ask you for help.

In my head I have a rough idea of ​​a solution, but I can’t implement it.
Here are my thoughts on this task.

1. Find the longest chain
2. Create an adjacency matrix for this chain
3. Change the initial adjacency matrix

Here is my attempts to implement this algorithm

```
    public void createChain() {
    int[][] maxMatrix = new int[adjMatrix.length][adjMatrix.length];
    Map<Integer, int[][]> curStr = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, int[][]>> maxStr = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < adjMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < adjMatrix.length; j++) {
            maxMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    createChain(maxMatrix, curStr, maxStr, 0);

    int maxKey = 0;
    for (int key : maxStr.keySet()) {
        if (key > maxKey) maxKey = key;
    }

    curStr = maxStr.get(maxKey);
    int maxKey1 = 0;
    for (int key : curStr.keySet()) {
        if (key > maxKey1) {
            maxKey1 = key;
        }
    }
    maxMatrix = curStr.get(maxKey1);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxMatrix.length; j++) {
            adjMatrix[i][j] = maxMatrix[i][j] == 1;
        }
    }

}

private void createChain(int[][] matrix, Map<Integer, int[][]> curStr, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, int[][]>> maxStr, int i) {
    for (int j = i; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        if (adjMatrix[i][j]) {

            if (!curStr.containsKey(i)) {
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
                curStr.put(i, matrix);
                i = j;

                maxStr.put(curStr.size(), curStr);
                Map<Integer, int[][]> copyOfCurStr = new HashMap<>();
                for (Integer key : curStr.keySet()) {
                    copyOfCurStr.put(key, copyOfCurStr.get(key));
                }

                int[][] copyOfMatrix = new int[matrix.length][matrix.length];
                for (int k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < matrix.length; l++) {
                        copyOfMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
                    }
                }
                createChain(copyOfMatrix, copyOfCurStr, maxStr, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the program works for some input, but not for other.
For example:

1. [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unyWd.png), [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blDw3.png). As you see, everything is working
2. [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnT0z.png), [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySBP6.png). The algorithm is not working correctly. The output should be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIVsk.png)

Comment: What is a "chain" ?

Comment: @amit A chain in a graph is a sequence of vertices from one vertex to another using the edges. The length of a chain is the number of edges used, or the number of vertices used minus one. A simple chain cannot visit the same vertex twice. The result of the algorithm should be a simple chain

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The terminology for this is a [**path**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)). And the problem you are trying to solve seems to be a variant of the [Hamiltonian Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)

Comment: @amit Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. It is implemented based on a modified Hamiltonian path search algorithm.

```
private boolean isSafe(int v, int graph[][], int path[], int pos) {
    if (graph[path[pos - 1]][v] == 0)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        if (path[i] == v)
            return false;

    return true;
}


private void hamCycleUtil(int graph[][], int path[], int pos, List<int[]> paths) {
    if (pos >= adjMatrix.length) {
        return;
    }

    for (int v = 0; v < adjMatrix.length; v++) {
        if (isSafe(v, graph, path, pos)) {
            path[pos] = v;

            int[] copyOfPath = new int[adjMatrix.length];
            System.arraycopy(path, 0, copyOfPath, 0, adjMatrix.length);
            paths.add(copyOfPath);


            hamCycleUtil(graph, path, pos + 1, paths);

            path[pos] = -1;
        }
    }
}


public int createChain() {
    List<int[]> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    int[][] matrix = new int[adjMatrix.length][adjMatrix.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < adjMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < adjMatrix.length; j++) {
            if (adjMatrix[i][j]) matrix[i][j] = 1;
            else matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    int[] path = new int[adjMatrix.length];
    Arrays.fill(path, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < adjMatrix.length; i++) {
        path[0] = i;
        hamCycleUtil(matrix, path, 1, paths);
    }

    int[] maxPath = new int[adjMatrix.length];
    Arrays.fill(maxPath, -1);
    int quantityOfElems = 0;
    int maxPathLength = 0;
    for (int[] chain : paths) {
        for (int value : chain) {
            if (value == -1) {
                break;
            }
            quantityOfElems++;
        }
        for (int value : maxPath) {
            if (value == -1) {
                break;
            }
            maxPathLength++;
        }
        if (quantityOfElems >= maxPathLength) {
            maxPath = Arrays.copyOf(chain, chain.length);
        }
        maxPathLength = 0;
        quantityOfElems = 0;
    }

    /*
    for (int value : maxPath) {
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();*/

    for (int i = 0; i < adjMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < adjMatrix.length; j++) {
            adjMatrix[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    quantityOfElems = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxPath.length - 1; i++) {
        if (maxPath[i] == -1 || maxPath[i + 1] == -1) break;
        adjMatrix[maxPath[i]][maxPath[i + 1]] = true;
        adjMatrix[maxPath[i + 1]][maxPath[i]] = true;
        quantityOfElems++;
    }

    return maxPath.length - quantityOfElems - 1;
}
```

Examples:

1. [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8dpf.png), [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQUSq.png)
2. [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkgrQ.png), [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwx0h.png)